# If Ethereum total supply is not capped, how is infinitely large integers prevented?

Tags: evm

If using infinite token supply, how is infinitely large integers avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't easily handle infinitely large token numbers, as you only have 256 bits. However, this still allows you to handle a very, very large number.

The ultimate supply of ETH isn't decided as the issuance necessary for reasonable security isn't yet known, but there is almost no chance it would be so big that it will overflow a uint256 in the next few millenia.

Comment: Has the idea to, once it approaches 256 bits, reset it to 10^nth of that max supply, and adjust the balance of all token holders accordingly, been mentioned or discussed any?

Comment: No need, just don't go anywhere near 256 bits.